# Jquery Datatable inside bootstrap d-flex is overflowing parent in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, datatables

Datatable renders outside or overflows from the parent  with d-flex class only in Internet Explorer.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="card-block">
          JQUERY DATATABLE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle for this problem https://jsfiddle.net/q9L2L6dz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is a reported issue and you may take a look [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22692).

A way to fix it is to set a fixed width to your row. Change this line:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:15px;">
```

to:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:15px;width: 900px;">
```

Of course, you need to use media queries instead of a static value like 900px.

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9L2L6dz/1/)